# Error: Inconsistent dependency lock file when extract resource into a module

Tags: terraform

I am new to terraform and as I extracted one of the resources into a module I got this:

```
Error: Inconsistent dependency lock file
│
│ The following dependency selections recorded in the lock file are inconsistent with the current
│ configuration:
│   - provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/heroku: required by this configuration but no version is selected
│
│ To update the locked dependency selections to match a changed configuration, run:
│   terraform init -upgrade
```

How I did?

First I had this:

```
provider "heroku" {}

resource "heroku_app" "example" {
  name   = "learn-terraform-heroku-ob"
  region = "us"
}

resource "heroku_addon" "redis" {
  app  = heroku_app.example.id
  plan = "rediscloud:30"
}
```

after that `terraform init` was runing without error also `terraform plan` was successfull.

Then I extracted the redis resource declaration into a module:

```
provider "heroku" {}

resource "heroku_app" "example" {
  name   = "learn-terraform-heroku-ob"
  region = "us"
}

module "key-value-store" {
  source = "./modules/key-value-store"

  app  = heroku_app.example.id
  plan = "30"
}
```

And the content of `modules/key-value-store/main.tf` is this:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    mycloud = {
      source  = "heroku/heroku"
      version = "~> 4.6"
    }
  }
}

resource "heroku_addon" "redis" {
  app  = var.app
  plan = "rediscloud:${var.plan}"
}
```

`terraform get` went well. but `terraform plan` showed me the above error!

Comment: Heroku is not an official Terraform provider, rather a verified one. That means you have to define `required_providers` on the module level as well.

Comment: @MarkoE I added this but no luck:
```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    mycloud = {
      source  = "heroku/heroku"
      version = "~> 4.6"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you please add the `required_providers` block you currently have and that is working to the question?

Comment: @MarkoE Can You please check it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this code to work, you have to have the `required_providers` blocks in both the root and child modules. So, the following needs to happen:

1. Add the `required_providers` block to the root module (this is what you have already)
2. Add the `required_providers` block to the child module and name it properly (currently you have set it to `mycloud`, and `provider "heroku" {}` block is missing)

The code that needs to be added in the root module is:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    heroku = {
      source = "heroku/heroku"
      version = "~> 4.6"
    }
  }
}

provider "heroku" {}

resource "heroku_app" "example" {
  name   = "learn-terraform-heroku-ob"
  region = "us"
}

module "key-value-store" {
  source = "./modules/key-value-store"

  app  = heroku_app.example.id
  plan = "30"
}
```

In the child module (i.e., `./modules/key-value-store`) the following needs to be present:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    heroku = { ### not mycloud
      source  = "heroku/heroku"
      version = "~> 4.6"
    }
  }
}

provider "heroku" {} ### this was missing as well

resource "heroku_addon" "redis" {
  app  = var.app
  plan = "rediscloud:${var.plan}"
}
```

This stopped working when the second resource was moved to the module as Heroku is not an official Terraform provider hence the provider settings are not propagated to the modules. For the unofficial providers (e.g., marked with `verified`), corresponding blocks of `required_providers` and `provider <name> {}` have to be defined. Also, make sure to remove the `.terraform` directory and re-run `terraform init`.